# Java Using OpenGL Stencil to create Outline

Tags: java, opengl, outline, stencil-buffer, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to render an outline of an object over the top of it but I'm having some difficulties. I'm not too good with OpenGL so most of it was from following tutorials. The desired effect is supposed to be something like this:

[image]

But this is the outcome at the moment:

[image]

The code I'm using to do this is:

```
GL11.glPushAttrib(GL11.GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
GL11.glClearStencil(0);
GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
GL11.glStencilFunc(GL11.GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFFFF);
GL11.glStencilOp(GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_REPLACE);
GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_FILL);
GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

// Render original.
this.doRender((AbstractClientPlayer) par1Entity, par2, par4, par6, par8, par9);

GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
GL11.glStencilFunc(GL11.GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 0xFFFF);
GL11.glStencilOp(GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_REPLACE);
GL11.glLineWidth(3.0f );
GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_LINE);
GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
GL11.glColor4f(1.0F, 0, 0, 0.5F);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// Render stencil.
this.doRender((AbstractClientPlayer) par1Entity, par2, par4, par6, par8, par9);

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glColor4f(1.0F, 1, 1, 1F);
GL11.glPopAttrib();
```

And `doRender` is the method already there to render the player.
Anything on this would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a stencil buffer? You typically request that when you set up your context/surface.